LVP adhesive is suddenly wet and seeping between the seams
I'm sure I used the correct glue and it was definitely tacky before installing the LVP. I installed it over terrazzo. I have done this many times. I had to remove the floors from two rooms and the glue was wetter than when it was even applied. It's literally seeping between the planks in the rest of the house now. AC is being run(we're in Florida)This has never happened before. The plumber says there is no leaks,but it's the only explanation I can come up with. The floors were just fine for 4 months and then this happened all of a sudden.

I'm sure I used the correct glue ... maybe you didn't  ... your post does not contain very much useful information

Exactly what glue di you use?  What LVP?   Most are click together to make a seal.  That alone should not let glue through.  Perhaps your not using the correct installation techniques. Not all LVP can be glued down.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Ok, ok...I used the 7050 universal flooring adhesive from HD to lay glue down vinyl planks. I have installed these glue down planks in at least 60 places so yes, I know what I'm doing.                 I troweled the glue onto the floor and let it dry until it was clear/tacky. NOW, after 5 months, the glue was suddenly soaking wet in the house but especially in two rooms so I removed the floors from those two rooms. The ONLY explanation I can come up with is a slab leak somewhere, but the plumber found no leaks. WHAT could cause the tacky glue to suddenly be WET EVERYWHERE?!

Also, the AC is being run everyday so it can't be the humidity.
